# Proof on lower integrals

Tags: real-analysis

I am asked to prove the following:
Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and suppose $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Prove if $L(f)=0$, then $f(x)=0$.

My attempt:

Proof by contrapositive: Assume $f(x)>0$ and define a partition $P={a,b}$. Then
$$L(f,P)=\inf\{f(x):x\in [a,b]\}\cdot (b-a)$$
Since $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$ and $(b-a)>0$, we have $L(f,P)>0$. Since $L(f) = \sup\{L(f,P^*):P^* \text{ is any partition}\}$, it must be that $L(f)>0$.

Is there anything incorrect with this proof? Our book is asking for is to do a much more difficult method (neighborhoods and such). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have negated the statement incorrectly. What you should prove is that if for **some** point $\xi$, $f(\xi)>0$, then $L(f)>0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $\xi$ there is a nbhd $(\xi-\delta,\xi+\delta)$ where $f>0$. Using this last observation and the fact that $f(x)\geqslant 0$ construct a partition $P_0$ such that $L(f,P_0)>0$, hence showing $L(f)=\sup\limits_{P\in\mathscr P} L(f,P)\geqslant L(f,P_0)>0$.

Comment: That's exactly what I was overlooking here. Fantastic, thanks!